# Adding class to <td> and <tr> in Vuetify data-table

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to give the tr and td a class name in my Vuetify data-table. But what am I doing wrong as this isn't working while I see everywhere this solution.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="customers" class="elevation-1">
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td class="test">{{ props.item.name}}</td>
      <td class="test1">{{ props.item.telephone}}</td>
      <td class="test2">{{ props.item.email}}</td>
      <td class="test3">{{ props.item.website}}</td>
      <td class="test4">{{ props.item.location}}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working codepen https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/QWjRpbP
VUE TEMPLATE:

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="px-2">
        <h2>Simple v-data-table with class in td</h2>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers"  :items="desserts"           class="elevation-4">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <td class="test">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
              <td class="test1">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
              <td class="test2 ">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
              <td class="test3">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
              <td class="test4">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
              <td class="test5">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
    </div>
</v-app>
```

CSS:

```
.test{color:red}
.test1{color:blue}
.test2{color:green}
.test3{color:yellow}
.test4{color:brown}
.test5{color:black}
```

VUE SCRIPT:

```
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
console.clear();
new Vue({
el: "#app",
data () {
  return {
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'start',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name',
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 200,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 200,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Eclair',
        calories: 300,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 23,
        protein: 6.0,
        iron: '7%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Cupcake',
        calories: 300,
        fat: 3.7,
        carbs: 67,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '8%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Gingerbread',
        calories: 400,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 49,
        protein: 3.9,
        iron: '16%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Jelly bean',
        calories: 400,
        fat: 0.0,
        carbs: 94,
        protein: 0.0,
        iron: '0%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Lollipop',
        calories: 400,
        fat: 0.2,
        carbs: 98,
        protein: 0,
        iron: '2%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Honeycomb',
        calories: 400,
        fat: 3.2,
        carbs: 87,
        protein: 6.5,
        iron: '45%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Donut',
        calories: 500,
        fat: 25.0,
        carbs: 51,
        protein: 4.9,
        iron: '22%',
      },
      {
        name: 'KitKat',
        calories: 500,
        fat: 26.0,
        carbs: 65,
        protein: 7,
        iron: '6%',
      },
    ],
  }
}
});
```

Comment: I don't want to style them, I want to give the tr and td a new class name.

Comment: Please have a look at the modified answer codepen - is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by a member of the [vuetify core team](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8028#issuecomment-515287810), the preferred way to override the rendering of individual table cells is to [use slots, as defined at the bottom of the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots).

Here's an example, where one of the properties of an item is rendered using a [chip](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chips/), while the rest of the table's columns use the default rendering.

```js
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.calories="{ item }">
      <v-chip :color="getColor(item.calories)">
        {{ item.calories }}
      </v-chip>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Note that the content inside the slot's `<template>` ends up being rendered *inside* the data table's `<td>` element, so you can't use this approach to add a class to the `<td>` element itself. But when you're only changing the markup for one column and would prefer to use the default rendering for all other columns, this is a useful tradeoff.